# How to convert nested loop to a LINQ-statement?

Tags: c#, linq

A rather simple question, but I can't work out how to convert a nested loop of such a kind:

```
for (var a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    for (var b = a + 1; b < n; b++)
        {
            //let here be a creation of a Tuple
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(a, b))
        }
}
```

to a LINQ-statement

upd:

```
I tried something like this:
from a in Enumerable.Range(0, n)
from b in Enumerable.Range(1, n)
...
```

but it didn't work

Comment: I assume you're looking for `list.AddRange(resultOfUsingLinq)`?  In any case, I love LINQ, but I have serious doubts you're going to end up with a LINQ solution that is going to be easier to read than what you have with your loops.

Comment: I am sure it will be less clear, but just in case I need to use a linq for this

Comment: Why would you "need" to use LINQ?  Is this for a school assignment?  (nothing wrong with that, but that's the only context in which such a requirement could possibly make sense)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to rewrite an interesting maths algorithm using only LINQ, so it's a kind of question of pure interest:)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  That's fair enough.

Comment: no problem, it's always nice to see an alternative opinion on a question

Comment: Normally for math you would like to have more CPU power, linq will make it worse.

Comment: Avoid using `Tuple.Create` for new code. This will create a reference type that will end up increasing pressure on GC. Instead, use a `ValueTuple` by just doing `(a, b)` instead of `Tuple.Create(a, b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here is one solution using Linq extension methods.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n-1)
    .SelectMany(
        a => Enumerable.Repeat(a, n-1 - a)
                .Zip( Enumerable.Range(a+1, n - (a+1)) )
    ).ToList();
```

How does it work? Well, look up the documentation for the involved Linq methods, that should provide sufficient insight to what's going on here with that ugly Linq construct  of mine. (Well, it's not only ugly, it's also so slow you are not at any risk of violating any speed limit...)

Note that the generated list is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<(int First, int Second)>`, which is using [C# tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), which are a value types and not to be confused with the *System.Tuple* type (which is a reference type) you used in the code in your question.

And here is a solution involving Linq query syntax:

```
var list = (
    from a in Enumerable.Range(0, n - 1)
    from b in Enumerable.Range(a + 1, n - (a + 1))
    select (a, b)
).ToList();
```

Comment: @TheBadBat, i just added an example with Linq query syntax. Seems my headache wasn't that bad already :-P

Answer (score 2):

It could be helpfull.

```
var result = (from a in Enumerable.Range(0, n - 1)
              from b in Enumerable.Range(a + 1, n - a - 1)
              select Tuple.Create(a, b)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Tuple.Create` will return `Tuple` instead of `ValueTuple` and should be avoided for new code due to unnecessary memory pressure. Instead, just `select (a, b)`. EDIT: I see you were basing your code on the OPs question. I've replicated the comment in the OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The @Community bot is worse than useless sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

You may use this:
`Enumerable.Range(0, n-1).ToList().ForEach(x => Enumerable.Range(x + 1, n-x-1).ToList().ForEach(y => list.Add(Tuple.Create(x,y))));`